# Rounded corners on `select` in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css

I was trying to change the rounding of the corners of a `<select>` element. I couldn't, using any of the `border-radius` properties (CodePen demo [here](https://codepen.io/ankush981/pen/dyYapEy)).

```css
select, input {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30px;
    border: none;
    padding: 18px 22px;
    border-radius: 0 1em 3em 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: #8842d5;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="pig">Pig</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text">
```

The result: 
[image]

AS you can see, the `<select>` doesn't budge.

I later came across [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15588) GitHub discussion from the Bootstrap project, which essentially says `<select>` elements cannot be styled using `border-radius` in Webkit-based browsers.

Okay, but what other techniques can I use to accomplish this? With reference to the screenshot I shared, is there no way to make the corners of the `select` look like the corners of the `input`?

Comment: share your code inside the question, not as a screentshot. It won't be difficult for such short code

Comment: @TemaniAfif I thought the image tells a better story. It has the code and the results.

Comment: no.we can only watch an image. With a code, we can run it, update it and easily provide an answer by copying it

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's why I included the direct link to CodePen, but suit yourself. I've added code directly to the question.

Comment: An external link can be invalid in the future because you can update the codepen at any time so this won't work too. It's not to suit me but to follow the rules:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @TemaniAfif True, true. Wow, the last rule actually says _not_ to include images of code! Stupid me.

Comment: I have added a snippet. But looks ok in Chrome and FF to me

Comment: @vals Maybe it's OS-specific? I'm on Mac. Where did you test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do much to directly modify the native `<select>` element. As you've already encountered `<select>` elements only accept a limited set of styling options. This [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Styling_with_CSS) elaborates on that further.

HOWEVER, you could wrap your `<select>` element with a container element and apply your styles there. Something like this should do the trick:

```css
body {
  /* Set a font-size for proper em sizing */
  font-size: 11px;
}

.select-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  padding: 18px 22px;
  border-radius: 0 1em 3em 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #8842d5;
}

.select-wrap select {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 22px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  right: 1.5em;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}


input {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  padding: 18px 22px;
  border-radius: 0 1em 3em 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #8842d5;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrap">
  <select>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="pig">Pig</option>
  </select>
  <span class="arrow">⬇</span>
</div>
<br>
<input type="text">
```

Note: Using `-webkit-appearance: none;` will hide your arrows so there's a custom `.arrow` element as well. It has `pointer-events:none` so that those clicks land on the `<select>` element instead.

Comment: Wow, that was pretty clever! Thank you, Matt. I'll save this answer in my notes because I spent several hours over this trying to find a solution!

Answer (score -1):

Try `-webkit-appearance: none` . But note you'll have to re-style everything, including the arrow icon (which you can refactor with a simple background-image).